# How do I send a string to a char array in Java?

Tags: java

```
String product = Integer.toString(w);

char[] original = String.toCharArray(product);
```

This is the code I have so far. The error says that I can't use toCharArray on String, but I looked in the documentation, and it is a listed method, so I'm kind of stuck.

Comment: it looks like you are trying to do something silly with `w`. can i ask why you want to get an integer to a char array?

Comment: I need to reverse the order of a number. Example: 123456 -> 654321

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`product.toCharArray()`

The toCharArray is not a static method, but is a method of a string that already exists, which is why it didn't compile for you.

Here is a longer example:

```
public class ToCharArrayString {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    //method converts complete String value to char array type value  
    String str = " einstein relativity concept is still a concept of great discussion";
    char heram[] = str.toCharArray();
    // complete String str value is been converted in to char array data by
    // the method
    System.out.print("Converted value from String to char array is:  ");
    System.out.println(heram);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the original reason was to reverse a number, my sugguestion is

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(Integer.toString(w));                System.out.println(sb.reverse().toString());

Comment: I agree with this, given that the comment below the OP says that this is what he was trying to achieve, except I'd always use the more lightweight `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer` when there is no concurrency to worry about.