# String to Array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, string

So my issue here is that I am trying to take in a String from user input, but then I need to convert that string into an array.
So as an example, the user inputted string would be `"Hello"`, and the array (named arr) would be: `arr[0]="H"` `arr[1] = "e"` and so on. If anyone can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I send a string to a char array in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659055/how-do-i-send-a-string-to-a-char-array-in-java)

Comment: Please do a search first. This question has been answered before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I split a String of dots?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29468875/how-can-i-split-a-string-of-dots)

Answer (score 1):

Use the standard library method:

```
char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
```

Documentation: [java.lang.String.toCharArray()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--)

Answer (score 1):

There's a built in function to convert a string to a character array:

```
String myString = ...;
char[] chars = myString.toCharArray();
```

If you need each character as a stirng, you can loop over the character array and convert it:

```
String myString = ...;
String[] result = new String[myString.length];
char[] chars = myString.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; ++i) {
    result[i] = String.valueOf(chars[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Read javadoc:
[String - toCharArray method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray())

> ```
> public char[] toCharArray()
> Converts this string to a new character array.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
 String hello = "Hello";
 String[] array = hello.split("");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.split("")` like

```
String[] arr = str.split("");
```

That will give you an array `arr` where each substring is one character

```
[H, e, l, l, o]
```

Another option might be [`String.toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) if a `char[]` is acceptable like

```
char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
```